running a SVM classification wont stop on my dataset
i have a dataset in kaggle and i must compare different ML algorithms accuracy for a binary classification problem. the shape of data is (500000,18).
but when i implement any kind of SVM like linear, rbf , poly ... the code wont stop even after a day and there is no error that i can figure out whats the problem. the data set addresss is :
https://www.kaggle.com/datasets/abolhasanml/diabetes-dataset-balanced
and my code is simple :
from sklearn.svm import SVC
clf = SVC(kernel='linear',C=0.001)
clf.fit(X_train, y_train)
i must mention that the accuracy isnt important i just must run different kernel for comparing the accuracies. is there any tips for running SVM for this dataset?

The kaggle link you provide is broken.
